# Why it will run a asyncio task that only be created but not be called in wait funcion?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'm practice asyncio in python, I create 2 tasks, and only join taks2 in the aws list as params for asyncio.wait.

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))

    aws = [task2]
    done, pend = await asyncio.wait(aws)

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    print(done, pend)

asyncio.run(main())
```

But the output is

```
started at 17:36:27
hello
world
finished at 17:36:29
```

The task1 is also be called, then I join task1 into aws list

```
aws = [task1, task2]
```

The print output is similar

```
started at 17:43:54
hello
world
finished at 17:43:56
```

So, Why I will get hello output when I only add task2 in aws list?

Comment: `create_task` schedules the task with the event loop. It will run the first chance it gets. Awaiting the task will block until it’s complete, but other sxheduled tasks will run as well.

Answer (score 0):

`asyncio.wait()` blocks until the awaitable(s) `aws` is complete but doesn't actually stop or have any effect on other scheduled tasks. So by the time `task2` is complete and the `asyncio.wait` is done, `task1` will have finished also since it's delay is smaller than that of task2.

Try changing the delay of `task1` to 5 or 10 seconds. If you set it longer than task2 you should see that only `world` will get printed. Since your `asyncio.wait` condition will be done before task1 is finished.